# How can I keep font-size from parent to children on styled-components?

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]

[image]

Hi, I am just started to use Styled-Components.

but a little bit weird thing I found.

As you can see, I don't know why All the children font-size is still 15px.

So how to parents font-size to children Elements?

Thank you.

Comment: Please avoid posting images, add the actual code instead

Comment: yeah I should have posted like that.. Thank you ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Add `inherit` as the default value:

```
const Div = styled.div`
  font-size: ${({ fontSize }) => (fontSize ? `${fontSize}px` : `inherit`)};
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Div fontSize={30}>
        First
        <Div>Second</Div>
      </Div>
      <Div>Default</Div>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit late-cache-x66o6]

Bonus: use [`styled-tools`](https://github.com/diegohaz/styled-tools) to remove all noise:

```
import { prop } from 'styled-tools';
// fontSize = `30px`
const Div = styled.div`
  font-size: ${prop(`fontSize`,`initial`);
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
`<Div fontSize='inherit'>Second</Div>`

Comment: or you can change you Div
`
const Div = stiled.div`
  font-size: ${props => props.fontSize || 'inherit'}
`
`

Comment: Is it impossible the inherit automatically?
Then I have to add inherit to all the children... :(

Comment: Dennis Vash posted the same bellow.